# css animation and keyframes

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to make a cube appear at the top of the page with css animation and keyframes.
but he appears at the beginning and only after does the animation.
how do i make it appear just from above?

I wanted that loads up the page and past two seconds the cube appeared.

```
<div id="cube"></div>


cube{
    position: relative;
    left:60px;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;     
    -webkit-animation-name: cube;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes cube {
    0% {top: -200px;}
    100% {top: 0;}
}
```

here is my example

http://jsfiddle.net/hmmatos/epZJB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I've misunderstood your question, but I'm not really sure how you mean so I've done two different examples hoping that at least one of them will help you.

[Demo One](http://jsfiddle.net/epZJB/3/)

What I've done here is I've added `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` which will maintaine the last state of the animation, making the div stay visible at the position you have set.

[Demo Two](http://jsfiddle.net/epZJB/4/)

In this demo, I'm animating the `opacity` instead of the positions.

So insted of sliding the div from `top: -80;` to `top: 0;` the div fill just fade into place. Also this example uses the `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

Here's a good resource if you want to read about CSS animations. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank @Christofer,
the problem is that I have an image and I want to do this type effect a menu that appears from top but when I load the page the image appears on the site and only after that does the effect and I wanted the image appears only from top

Comment: Thank @Christofer, i figured out must be backwards :)